# How can I search and replace some column values based on values in another table?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    ID VARCHAR(15),
    Value INT
);
INSERT INTO Table1 (`ID`, `Value`)
  VALUES
('A', 21),
('B', 50),
('C', 10);

CREATE TABLE Table2 (
    ID VARCHAR(15)
);
INSERT INTO Table2 SELECT ID FROM Table1;
```

I have to rename all the IDs in Table2 whose values in table1 < 20  to "Low_<ID Name>". After this, "Table2" should look like:

> ```
> mysql> SELECT ID FROM Table2
> +-------+
> | ID    |
> +-------+
> | A     |
> | B     |
> | Low_C |
> +-------+
> ```

What query will do this?

Comment: Changing primary key values is a *very* bad idea

Comment: ID isn't a primary key. In my original database I have a composite key(not listed here). This is a very rough representation of the original schema.

Comment: Proper [sample code](http://sscce.org/) (here, SQL statements) is more useful than any ad hoc schema and sample data format. Please use `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT ... VALUES` for samples. Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UPDATE Table2
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.ID=Table1.ID
SET Table2.ID = CONCAT('Low_',Table2.ID)
WHERE Table1.Value<20
```

But as @Phil said...are you sure you want to change your (presumably) primary key `ID`?

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE Table2 SET ID = CONCAT('Low_', ID)
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Table1 WHERE `Value` < 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like

```
UPDATE Table2 SET ID = "Low_" + ID 
  WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Table1 WHERE Value < 20)
```